# How to post HTML content in facebook wall using facebook api in php

Tags: php, facebook

How to post HTML content in facebook wall using facebook api in php

I have used below codes but not working

```
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',array( 'message' => '<h1>This is my demo Face book application!</h1>'));
```

And I used as below code using php concatenate the HTML string

```
 $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',array( 'message' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!' . $htmlStr));
```

but not working and getting below error

```
OAuthException: (#1) An unknown error occurred
```

Any please help me.

Comment: Do you have a oauth token and are you sure it's valid?
You can test it by pointing your browser to https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=...

Comment: And, by the way, you cannot post HTML to the wall, only plain text.

Comment: I need to post logo image with description i tired below code but not working

$attachment = array('message' => 'some meesgae', 'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!', 'caption' => "Caption of the Post", 'link' => 'http://mylink.com', 'description' => 'this is a description', 'picture' => 'http://mysite.com/pic.gif', 'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Get Search',     'link' => 'http://www.google.com')) );


    $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$attachment);

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post HTML in a Facebook wall post.

Comment: Claude Vedovini actually posted that [as a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688367/how-to-post-html-content-in-facebook-wall-using-facebook-api-in-php/15081277#comment3888623_3688367) the day after this question was posted.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Yeah, not sure why this post was on top of the recent posts. Figured it might as well have an actual answer.

Comment: Good point. This sort of thing is a little weird; it also looks like the OP had another problem with their code. I actually voted to close the whole thing as "Too Localized", but... eh! :)